# How to add 3 large integers efficiently using GMP

Tags: c++, performance, gmp, bignum

I want to do x = a + b + c on ~2048 bit signed integers. Currently my code looks like

```
mpz_add(x, a, b);
mpz_add(x, x, c);
```

Is there a single function to do this? This happens many many times in my application. I have profiled my code and the 3-way add step is taking up a significant portion of the runtime. If there's an alternative way to do this in a single pass that might help.

Comment: I don't think that an appropriate `operator+()`overload would gain anything significant in performance of gmp.

Comment: Yeah, operator overloading would be just some syntactic sugar. The underlying algorithm could iterate the limbs on one pass vs the two pass is what I'm thinking.

Comment: It is hard to answer without the context. Is x some new variable each time, or one that you reuse in a loop? Are all numbers as likely to be the same size / sign? Etc. I doubt there is much to gain from a 3-way adder, but who knows... Did you profiler specify which part of mpz_add is taking time?

Comment: People think that temporaries in evaluation are going to be a problem with C++, but the [`gmpxx`](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface.html#C_002b_002b-Class-Interface) library is well-designed for such expressions, and employs modern techniques like move semantics.

Answer (score 0):

I've used MPFR extensively and I've looked through nearly every part of the documentation. I'm almost certain that nothing like this exists in MPFR and as such, I'm almost certain nothing like this exists in GMP.

One solution could be to switch to MPFR and use [Pavel Holoborodko's MPFR C++](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/mpfr/#license) which adds operators for MPFR functions. I can't imagine that this would help performance (although it probably wouldn't affect it much), it's under a GPL, and you'd have to install another library, but it would combine the operations.

I don't know of any fast algorithms that when adding three numbers don't just add two of them and then add the last number in behind the scenes. I don't think that combining these two operations into one operation using any library in any language would help performance. Arbritrary precision is just slow, even using GNU MP. I've got a comparison of the speeds [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177557/mandelbrot-render-speed-with-arbritary-precision-vs-double-precision) on Code Review if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Calling twice the functions won't incur in a noticeable overhead. However, the reallocation of x, if needed, can be very slow. To avoid this, you can measure the sizes of a, b and c and make sure x has allocated the maximum size of the three numbers plus 2 (1 bit for addition, in the worst case). You can use

```
mpz_init2(x, maxsize+2);
```

or, if x was already initialized,

```
if (mpz_sizeinbase(x, 2) < maxsize+2)
  mpz_realloc2(x, maxsize+2);
```